# Is there a way to speed up sending data from Node.js to the client for large amounts of data?

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am currently creating a program that utilizes Node.js/Socket.io with a mysql database (this is my first node project).  There are 2 ways I am utilizing Node.js:

- Any changes made on a client to the data is sent to Node.js to be sent to the other clients and dealt with.  This works great.
- **Upon connection, all data relevant to the program is sent to the client.**

Everything was working the way that I wanted it to, until I did testing for a lot of data.

I believe I am missing the boat here.  I am wondering if sending all data to the clients is stupid, if I should simply do it through PHP instead of Node.js or if I should just deal with non-snappiness in the program and load the data as needed instead of all at once.  The reason I did this was because I want the program to be very fast and it will rarely need to be reloaded, but now I am looking at 1 minute initial load times with a lot of data - and connecting more than one client at once, it doubles, triples, etc. the load time like they are in line...

If it is not stupid and is possible, what is the optimal way to do this so that clients do not affect each others load times and so that I can get increased load speed?

---

As a side note, it actually seems strange because when I load the page and look at the console, the object that is by far the largest SEEMS to be fully loaded in the client, while my Node.js command prompt is still going crazy spitting out that very same info.

Comment: How much is _"a lot of data"_?

Comment: An array of 2475 objects with about 12 key value pairs each.

Comment: How much is that in bytes?

Comment: Added this script to my code:

http://www.russwurm.com/uncategorized/calculate-memory-size-of-javascript-object/

and it came out to 848558 bytes.

Comment: That's not a negligible amount of data in any situation. I think it might be worthwhile to consider loading incrementally, if possible.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Doing so would fix my initial delay upon loading the program, however I'll trade that off for a 500ms or so delay on loading individual views.  Not that big of a deal IMO but when replacing a native windows app with no delay between views, it sucks.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Do you always need to send the entire amount of data to a client?

Comment: It is a point of sale system for a restaurant.  What this data is are items that have been ordered (and entered in).  So currently I am trying to send them all to all clients on load so that when a table is pulled up, all the order items are already there...

The alternate route would be to send the order items of the table the client is looking at when requested, but then there is the problem, the half second load time whenever a table is pulled up.  The only way I can think to get rid of that delay would be to send all the data to all clients (as I'm doing now)....

Comment: ...but then I have the initial load time issue like I do now.  Is it normal that multiple clients can't be receiving the data at the same time from node and they have to wait their turn to receive it?  Wondering if I'm doing something wrong there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115424/discussion-between-jdgower-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to look at the *source* of the slowness.  It's very unlikely to be the language (but it might be).  Is it

- retrieval from the database? (consider some sort of caching like memcache)
- processing in server? (cache the processed results, use a faster server or a faster language)
- transmission over the net? (reduce the data being sent, improve the compression)
- somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It is likely the transmission.  Bear in mind that this is all local at the moment (same machine for server and client).  The reason I say transmission is because if I comment out the emit statement (and still do the db lookup, javascript loops, etc.) there is no delay at all to get to the end.

Comment: Simply put...should it be slow?  The array of 2475 objects and takes about 20-30 seconds (usually) to make it to the client.

Comment: @jdgower -- then you're on the right track.  Try accessing it over the local network using `curl` or similar (fast) client and see how long it takes.